# JPA Data not getting saved when I use multiple Threads

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I was trying to use Multi-thread to process task in  background and get response quicker.
Below is my method from controller

```
 public Response pullSourceData(@RequestParam String jobType){
        if(jobType.length()>0){
            LOG.info("Started Job processing of type:" +jobType);
           new Thread(() -> jobService.processJob(jobType)).start();
        }else{
            LOG.warn("jobType parameter is missing");
        }
        //jobService.processJob(jobType);
        Message emptyResultSetMessage = Message.create("TEST CODE", "Job status", "This is  sourceData Job");
        MetaData metaData = new MetaData();
        metaData.addMessage(emptyResultSetMessage);
        return Response.assemble().addMetadata(metaData).build(ResponseHttpStatus.OK, null);
  }
```

My service class

```
  
@Service
public class JobServiceImpl implements JobService {
    @Autowired
    ProcessJob processJob;
   public void processJob(String jobType) {

            try {
                processJob.updateData(jobType);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              //  e.printStackTrace();
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            }
    }   
}
```

ProcessJob class

```
@Component
public class ProcessJob {
    @Autowired
    LogDAO logDAO; 
    
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public boolean updateData(String jobType) {
        //Some business logic
        logDAO.save(logDTO);
    }
}
```

If I create new thread my traction not getting saved in database(I don't see new data in database). If I comment thread and process it using main thread only it works fine.

I have tried multiple options like adding @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) on prcoesJob() method.

I have tried @Async as well. In call cases data is not getting saved in database. For data retrieval I don't see any issues.

Any idea what's Wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the  jobService.processJob code as well?

Comment: @SándorJuhos I added code for processJob

Comment: Is there any exception in your logs?